# mySQL insert issue from web jsp form containing forward slash character

Tags: java, mysql, jsp

I have a jsp form where the user can include the following string for example:

This is a test with /

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

 description = request.getParameter("description ");
 String mysqlQuery= "insert into data values (default,'" + description + "');";
 int Res = St.executeUpdate(mysqlQuery);    
 ...
 }
```

Here is the problem. When I go and check mySQL table data, I see that the description column is missing the / :

This is a test with

To workaround that, I tried to use the String.replaceAll method, but this method does not like the '/' or '\' either and the compiler will error. Is there a better way to address this?

Comment: Use a prepared statement. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html. Your code is a huge invitation for [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Comment: Have you checked if the value of description is not null?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well,
Can yo try this once?

```
preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data (default, description, .., ....) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
preparedStatement.setInt(1,0);
preparedStatement.setString(2, data.getDescription());
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(3, ...);
.....

preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
```

Note: 
Advantages of a **PreparedStatement**:

- Precompilation and DB-side caching of the SQL statement leads to
  overall **faster execution** and the ability to **reuse** the same SQL
  statement in batches.
- Automatic prevention of **SQL injection attacks** by builtin escaping of
  quotes and other special characters. Note that this requires that you
  use any of the PreparedStatement setXxx() methods to set the values
- PreparedStatement is a **very good defense** (but not foolproof) in preventing SQL injection attacks.

Thanks.

Comment: This worked but need to change the code for the DEFAULT keyword. Thanks a lot.